# Multi dimensional array. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function:

```
function getDecision($num_players, $decisionType, $stage){

echo "in the function 1: ".$num_players."<br/>";
echo "in the function 2: ".$decisionType."<br/>";
echo "in the function 3: ".$stage."<br/>";

$x = mysql_query("

    SELECT `decisionValue` FROM `teamdecision` WHERE `decisionType` = '$decisionType' && `period`= '$stage'

    ")or die($x."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

            $y = array();
            $i="0";
            while ($i<($num_players) && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($x))
            {

            $y[$i] = $row['decisionValue'];
            $i++;

            }

            return ($y);
}
```

Y will be populated with a number of values depending on the `$num_players`. I am calling the function as follows:

```
$value = array();
$name = array();

for ($j=0;$j<$num_players;$j++){
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
$name[0] = "SUconsultant";
$name[1] = "marketT";
$name[2] = "sector";
$name[3] = "saleprice";

echo $name[$i]."<br/>";

$value[$i] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$i], $currentStage)."<br/>";

echo "Value = ".$value[$j][$i]."<br/>";
}
}
```

As you can see I am doing this wrong. I need to output the data located in `$value` however I am confused with how multi dimensional arrays work. I understand I need to read up on the subject, if possible can you point me to a suitable learning source?

**So I changed up the code so that the following is being used to produce an output below:**

```
$value = array();
$name = array();

for ($j=0;$j<$num_players;$j++){
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
$name[0] = "SUconsultant";
$name[1] = "marketT";
$name[2] = "sector";
$name[3] = "saleprice";

echo $name[$i]."<br/>";

$value[$i] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$i], $currentStage)."<br/>";

echo "Value = ".$value[$j][$i]."<br/>";
}
}
```

[image]

**I expected to output as follows:**

`$value[0]` should contain $y which then contains each SUconsultant value. `$value[1]` should contain $y which then contains each marketT value and so on.

Comment: IS `for ($i=0;$j<4;$i++)` the `i` there intentional? Because I think not...

Comment: Well, `$i="0";` is defining $i as a string - it'll work but there's no need for quotes in the first place.

Comment: Sorry you're right I fixed both commented problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked, after a lot of playing around it seems that the `[]` after of
the `value` array was also needed? At least I think so

```
$value = array();
$name = array();

for ($j=0;$j<$num_players;$j++){
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
$name[0] = "SUconsultant";
$name[1] = "marketT";
$name[2] = "sector";
$name[3] = "saleprice";

echo $name[$i]."<br/>";

$value[] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$i], $currentStage);

//echo "Value = ".$value[$i]."<br/>";

echo "<br/><hr/>";
echo "Value = ".$value[$i][$j]."<br/><hr/>";
}
}
```

Output:

[image]

And now I have changed to:

```
$value[] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$i], $currentStage);

echo "Team ".$j." ".$name[$i]." = ".$value[$i][$j]."<br/>";
```

To get my eventual goal of:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a `$j` in your first for loop, but setting and incrimenting `$i` in it.  Maybe change them to `$j` as well.

**EDIT**

It actually looks like you have an issue with where you are returning the data:

```
echo "Value = ".$value[$j][$i]."<br/>";
```

This should be (it appears):

```
for ($f = 0; $f < $num_players; $f++){
    echo "Value = ".$value[$i][$f]."<br/>";
}
```

Since you are currently on `$value[$i]` by the time you reach this point, then you need it to echo out one for each player.

Comment: I have done that, now it seems that `$name` isn't passing to the function correctly. Only the first letter of each string.

Comment: Try specifying `$name = array();` at the top under `$value = array();`.

Comment: Yes just did that. Please see above for an edit. I'm writing it now.

Comment: Can you put some example output of what you are expecting back as well?

Comment: @NeverPhased  Ignore what I just posted.  It looks like you are only expecting one value result per pass.  I guess my question then would be why are you returning an array at all if you only expect one number?

Comment: $value[0] should contain $y which then contains each `SUconsultant` value. $value[1] should contain $y which then contains each `marketT` value and so on.

Comment: Going off your first "Expected" result return, you should get an array back of 2 different values since you are passing in a parameter of 2 for `$num_players`.  So `$y` should be an array of 2, which means that `$value[$i]` should hold an array of 2 as well.  `$value[$i][0]` and `$value[$i][1]`, which then means you should be echoing two values in that case.  Or so I'm just assuming that's what your goal was.

Comment: Try putting that for statement in place that I mentioned in my code above and see if that gives you what you are looking for just in case.

Comment: See my answer below, I got it :) Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0;$j<4;$i++){
```

should be

```
for ($j=0;$j<4;$j++){
```

And

```
$value[$i] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$i], $currentStage)."<br/>";
```

should be

```
$value[$j] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$j], $currentStage)."<br/>";
```

Comment: Changing that is not making a difference, it seems that the strings are not passing to the function correctly. Please see my edit above.

Comment: You did change the first part, but not this line: $value[$j] = getDecision($num_players, $name[$j], $currentStage)."<br/>";

Comment: I tried it but didn't work, see my solution I have answered this question myself after a lot of tweaking.